# Verify #include uses a header generated with cmake's ExternalProject_Add rather than the system equivalent

Tags: c++, cmake

I've added `zlib` to a CMake project like so:

```
project(zlib)

include(ExternalProject)

# set some variables

ExternalProject_Add(zlib_proj # boring stuff omitted ...
                   )

add_library(zlib SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(zlib zlib_proj)
set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES
  # ...
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${INCLUDE_DIR}"
)
```

I've chosen to build `zlib` within my CMake project instead of using the system `zlib.so` in order to guarantee that the same `zlib` is used regardless of where the project is cloned and built (this choice is not up for debate).

Elsewhere, another target links `zlib` through `target_link_libraries`. In a source file in that dependent target, I `#include <zlib.h>`. It compiles fine, and I am fairly certain that `zlib.so` is built and linked correctly as well. However, `<zlib.h>` is available from the system as well. I could probably manually verify that I am including the `<zlib.h>` in `${INCLUDE_DIR}` by adding a bogus variable and using it in a dependent source file, but I really would like to automatically assert that the correct file is included during any compilation on any machine. Determining that the included `zlib.h` lives somewhere in the CMake build directory is probably sufficient.

I believe `CheckIncludeFileCXX` doesn't quite solve the problem; I need to verify which `zlib.h` is *actually* included in a specific source file. Knowing that my locally provided `zlib.h` can be included at all is certainly a prerequisite, but it doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: Just a random suggestion - if you generate the dependency file for the given `.cpp` (`-MD -MF <dependency file>`) you could then add a custom build command that verifies that for your file of interest the zlib header dependency comes from the correct path. If this actually achieves what you need, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis This sounds like it would work for me! If you could also include the cleanest way to generate those dependencies only for a specific target or even just the single source file, that would be great. I'm not super familiar with their use, although I've learned a little through experimentation since you left this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by making the compiler generate the dependency files for the needed `.cpp` file and then adding a custom build step that verifies the path of `zlib.h` by `grep` or any other means. So, in short (since I am not a CMake expert):

- Add `-MD -MF` to C/C++ flags (or maybe CMake has some nice way to enable dependency generation or maybe even does it by default - not really sure).
- Add a `add_custom_command` (or again maybe there is something nicer) to verify the path of `<zlib.h>` in the generated dependency file.